# vuejs emit from a component of a component to the parent

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using a component2 in my component1. I want to emit a parent function from component2 but only component1 is called in parent.

At the moment I'm emit in component2 and listening in component1. Then emit in component1 again and listening in parent.

> My current code:

```js
// Emit the toggle-filter in component2
Vue.component('component2', {
    template: `<div  @click="$emit('toggle-filter')"></div>`
});

// Capture it in component1, the emit again
Vue.component('component1', {
    template: `<div>
                    <component2 @toggle-filter="toggleFilter"></component2>
                </div>`,
    methods: {
        toggleFilter () {
            this.$emit('toggle-filter');
        },
    }
});

// At last, capture it in parent
new Vue({
    el: '#filters',
    template: `<div id="filters">
                <component1 @toggle-filter="toggleFilter"></component1>
            </div>`,
    methods: {
        toggleFilter () {
            console.log('filter toggled');
        }
    }
});
```

> What I want to achieve is something like below.

```js
// Emit toggle-filter in component2
Vue.component('component2', {
    template: `<div  @click="$emit('toggle-filter')"></div>`
});

Vue.component('component1', {
    template: `<div>
                    <component2></component2>
                </div>`
});

// Then capture it in parent
new Vue({
    el: '#filters',
    template: `<div id="filters">
                <component1 @toggle-filter="toggleFilter"></component1>
            </div>`,
    methods: {
        toggleFilter () {
            console.log('filter toggled');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you want to archieve with this?.

Comment: I updated my goal in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Vue 2, methods related to cross-component communication has been removed, and it's [recommended](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Non-flux-state-management-use-with-caution) to centralise data and manage shared state using Vuex. If the example pattern occurs a lot in your app, consider to use Vuex instead.

Vue still allows to create an event hub and let components communicate through the hub globally. But remember that it's considered anti-pattern.

```
var eventHub = new Vue()

Vue.component('component2', {
    template: `<div  @click="toggleFilter"></div>`,
    methods: {
        toggleFilter() {
            eventHub.$emit('toggle-filter')
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('component1', {
    template: `<div><component2 ></component2></div>`
}

new Vue({
    el: '#filters',
    template: `<div id="filters"><component1></component1></div>`,
    created() {
        eventHub.$on('toggle-filter', this.toggleFilter)
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        eventHub.$off('toggle-filter', this.toggleFilter)
    },
    methods: {
        toggleFilter () {
            console.log('filter toggled');
        }
    }
});
```